# Hoeffding's Inequality and Generalization Error

Tags: real-analysis, probability, inequality

Let $L:\mathbb{R}^2\to [0,1]$ be a function and $\mathcal{F}$ be a countably infinite family of functions $f_j:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$. Let $T=\{(x_i,y_i):1\leq i\leq n\}$ be such that $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are realizations of some distribution $X$ and that $y_1,\dots,y_n$ are realizations of some distribution $Y$. For each $f\in \mathcal{F}$, define
$$E(f)=\mathbb{E}L(Y,f(X)),\qquad E_n(f)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nL(y_i,f(x_i))$$
Suppose that there exists a constant $V$ such that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a function $f_j\in \mathcal{F}$, where $j\leq \left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right)^V$, such that
$$\sup_{x,y}\left|L(y,f(x))-L(y,f_j(x))\right|\leq \epsilon\qquad \forall f\in \mathcal{F}$$
Then for fixed $\epsilon\in (0,\infty), \delta\in (0,1)$, how large does $n$ have to be so as to guarantee that with probability at least $1-\delta$ the following holds?
$$E(f)\leq E_n(f)+\epsilon\qquad \forall f\in \mathcal{F}~.$$

---

I know a little about the so-called $VC$-dimension but I don't think it's useful to consider that for this problem. So here is what I tried.

It suffices to prove that, for a properly chosen $n$, with probability at least $1-\delta$
$$\sup_{f\in \mathcal{F}}\left[E(f)-E_n(f)\right]\leq \epsilon$$
Choose $j\leq (\frac{2}{\epsilon})^V$ such that
$$\sup_{x,y}\left|L(y,f(x))-L(y,f_j(x))\right|\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}\qquad \forall f\in \mathcal{F}$$
Observe that
$$E(f)-E_n(f)=E(f)-E(f_j)+E(f_j)-E_n(f)$$
By linearity of expected value and the assumption,
$$E(f)-E(f_j)=\mathbb{E}\left(L(Y,f(X))-L(Y,f_j(X))\right)\leq \mathbb{E}\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$
Since the supremum of the sum of two functions cannot exceed the sum of their suprema, we have that
$$\sup_{f\in \mathcal{F}}\left[E(f)-E_n(f)\right]\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}+\sup_{f\in \mathcal{F}}\left(E(f_j)-E_n(f)\right)$$
But how do I bound the second term above **using Hoeffding's inequality?** Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks!